# Printf does not produce any output

Tags: objective-c, printf

I have the following code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Calculator* calc;
    calc = [[Calculator alloc]init];
    float answer = [calc add:4.0 to:3.0];
    printf("Answer is:", answer);
    return NSApplicationMain(argc,  (const char **) argv);
}
```

But it doesn't work. I know my `printf` arguments are wrong, but I'm not sure how to fix them.

Answer (score 6):

Use [printf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/) like this:

```
printf("Answer is: %f", answer);
```